# Ordinary differential equations solving a Hamiltonian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across an example to solve the Quantisation of the Harmonic Oscillator, however I'm struggling on the maths as there are gaps in the notes. 
We are given the equation for a classical harmonic oscillator,
$H(p,q)={p^2}/{2m}+(mw^2q^2)/2$
and the solution of the Hamiltonian which I solved as:
${dq/dt}=\delta{H}/\delta{p}=p/m$ and ${dp/dt}=-\delta{H}/\delta{q}=-mw^2q$

I then calculated $p=(dp/dt)(1/w^2)$ and $q=-(dq/dt)(1/w^2)$

However, the solutions in my notes are $p(t)=-mwASin(wt+\theta)$ and $q(t)=ACos(wt+\theta)$

The rest of the example I could follow but I cannot figure out how they got these. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a system of first order linear ODE. The way to solve these is often taught as an application in linear algebra or calc/diff eq.

Comment: yes but why did they pick the constants in front the way they did here

Comment: The constant $\ A\ $ in front of $\ q\ $ is arbitrary until you're given an initial condition.  The one in front of $\ p\ $ comes from the fact that $\ p = m\frac{dq}{dt}\ $.